# Is there a way to change your location when debugging on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, desktop-application, windows-10

I am currently testing an application on Visual Studio 2015 and only have access to testing it on my local machine. The application is testing location specific data and I want more data. Is there a way to move where your machine thinks it is, while running an application, so I can get the proper data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done it myself, but if you debug with the simulator you can change your location.

[image: Visual Studio debug simulator option]

Inside the simulator, click the globe icon on the right:

[image: Set Location in Simulator]

Comment: I just noticed that the tag on the question is "desktop-application". This answer may not work, but is still worth a try.  To get the simulator you have to create a blank Windows Universal app. Then debug it as above using the simulator dropdown. Stop the debugger and the simulator should still be running. After that set your location as above and launch your application from inside the simulator and see if the location is changed.

Comment: That would work (didn't see the simulator and the emulator for a phone doesn't work on my old surface - lack of memory) BUT when I run the simulator I don't have the globe button on the side... though I have the other buttons shown in your picture.

Comment: I used VS 2013 to start the simulator and the button is there. I tried VS 15 and no globe icon.  Strange, as the [docs for VS 15 indicate that the set location functionality is there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh441475.aspx).